# find command behaviour inside for loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, find

I have following part of code inside bash script.

```
for dir in $(find /etc/aaa -type d -maxdepth 1)
do
 #my code
done

#my code
```

if `/etc/aaa` directory is not present then i want to exit script with some error.

I am aware that i can test existence of directory before executing for loop.

But i want to know is there any other way (short way in for loop only) so that if directory `/etc/aaa` is not present then it should exit else script should continue.

In current situation, script give error of that `find: /etc/aaa: No such file or directory` and continues to remaining part after for loop.

Also exit status of for loop is 0.

Comment: Bad syntax on the `find`, the type should be "d" for directory rather than "dir" ?

Comment: @steve thnx ..it was typo error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
if dirs="$(find /etc/aaa -type dir -maxdepth 1 2> /dev/null)"; then
    for dir in ${dirs}; do
        # Your code
    done
    # Your code
else
    # find failed, generate error
fi
```

Comment: thnx for ur answer. It is helpful but can i put something like below instead of using if condition. "test -d /etc/aaa && for dir in $(find /etc/aaa -type dir -maxdepth 
;do
 #my code
;done || exit 1"

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why you would want to exit the loop in the middle of it's execution. I do not think it is worth executing the loop if the directory you desire is not present.

I think you should do something along the lines of:

```
if [ ! -d /etc/aaa ]; do
    echo "Error"
    exit 1
else
    for files in $(ls /etc/aaa); do
        # code
    done
    # more code
fi
```

If this is not at all what you are looking for, please explain what it is that you want to accomplish.

Comment: Be careful trying to [parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) as you'll run into problems with spaces in filenames and lots of other things.  Also, your `ls` will get both files and directories in `/etc/aaa`, while it seems the OP only wants directories there

Comment: I appreciate the advice. This was simply an example for the OP showing how this could be handled. I had no intention of him/her to actually use the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easier to do a logic test before the loop.
But this is a hack n' slash into the for-statement:

```
for dir in `! find /etc/aaa -type d -maxdepth 1 2>/dev/null && echo error && exit`;
do
//your code
done

//your code
```

This will also suppress the stderr of **find**.